# I want to know which font is used

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, pdftex, times

[image]

Could someone please tell me what font this is? It looks so beautiful and elegant. Particularly, look at the square root symbol and the `\pi`. I have been looking for this font for a very long time, but to no avail. The pi you see in the image is a part of the universal math font, which I have in Word, but am unable to import it in XeLaTeX.

Please let me know which font this is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: There are literally thousands of typefaces out there so it's hard to tell from one image, but you could start by trying https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ or if that doesn't work there are "font identifiers" available online, such as at fontsquirrel.com.

Comment: Do you have `PDF`? It is much easier to know the font name from the PDF....

Comment: the question is most likely a duplicate of this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture  which will show you how to get the font names from a PDF